# For loop in async function and timing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, for-loop, mongoose

I am querying my mongodb for the user's email that is being passed through a session. When that email is found it looks for that user's friends, and those friends are **supposed** to be passed to the `usersFriends` array which is then sent in the chunk to the browser. I included all the code in this block even though the transaction block isn't really pertinent or so I think.

**The Problem:** is that the `usersFriends` array is outputting an empty array everywhere except when the `console.log` is inside the `for` loop. Thoughts?

```
app.get('/api/chunk', function(req, res){

var last5;
var usersFriends = [];

Transaction.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(5).exec(function(err, docs){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        last5 = docs;           
    }
});

User.findOne({ email: req.user.email }, function(err, user){
    if (!user) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < user.friends.length; i++) {
            (function(cntr){
            User.findOne({ email: user.friends[cntr].email}, function(err, result) {
                result.password = "Sneaky sneaky"
                var name = result.firstName + " " + result.lastName;                    
                usersFriends.push({
                    name: name,
                    index: cntr
                });
            });                 
            })(i);

            var chunk = {
                "friends": usersFriends,
                "transactions": last5
            };
        }       }console.log(usersFriends); // empty array 
});

});
```

Comment: Trying to use a `for` loop index in an async callback.   There are hundreds of dups of this.  I will see if I can find one.

Comment: I am having a little bit of trouble understanding this after looking at that post. Here I have two async functions, so the `usersFriends` data needs to go through two async functions. I have little understanding of closures, so I am thoroughly confused . I updated the code to use the for loop solution from the referenced post.

Comment: I reopened it.  That did solve your first issue with the `for` loop index.  But, you appear to have additional problems in that you need to know when all the inner `.findOne()` operations are done so you can then know when to use the `userFriends` result.  There are many dups of that part too.

Comment: Great thanks! That is the problem yes, once the async functions are done, i need the usersFriends data to be passed back outside to the `usersFriends` array so it can be sent with the chunk.

Comment: And FYI, this isn't a scope issue.  It's a timing issue.  Asynchronous operations finish sometime in the future.  You are doing a `console.log(userFriends)` before any of the async responses have finished.

Comment: I realized that, I changed the question name

Comment: See the techniques used in this answer for maintaining a counter of when all responses are done (also can use promises): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051467/why-is-this-fs-readfile-loop-not-pushing-its-results-to-my-array/29051632#29051632.  Other examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989375/ajax-asynch-callback-working-correctly-but-how-do-i-wait-for-the-returned-values/24989456#24989456 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119280/how-to-collect-the-value-to-an-array-in-nodejs-loop/27119344#27119344

Answer (score 0):

Combining all the various things we've discussed in comments for this list of changes:

1. Pass the cntr in an IIFE so it is uniquely captured for each separate `.findOne()` request.
2. In each response, check if this is the last one done so we know that all results have arrived.
3. Start the `.findOne()` operations from the completion of the `Transaction.find()` operation (since I don't know that operation, I'm guessing how this particular aspect should be implemented, but you should be able to see the general idea).

Though would result in this code:

```
app.get('/api/chunk', function(req, res) {

    var last5;
    var usersFriends = [];

    Transaction.find().sort({
        $natural: -1
    }).limit(5).exec(function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            last5 = docs;
            User.findOne({
                email: req.user.email
            }, function(err, user) {
                if (!user) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    var totalCnt = user.friends.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < totalCnt; i++) {
                        (function(cntr) {
                            User.findOne({
                                email: user.friends[cntr].email
                            }, function(err, result) {
                                result.password = "Sneaky sneaky"
                                var name = result.firstName + " " + result.lastName;
                                usersFriends.push({
                                    name: name,
                                    index: cntr
                                });
                                if (usersFriends.length === totalCnt) {
                                    // all results are done here
                                    // you can create the final response
                                    var chunk = {
                                        "friends": usersFriends,
                                        "transactions": last5
                                    };
                                }
                            });
                        })(i);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```